# How to cycle through the index of an array?

Tags: python

line 14 is where my main problem is.i need to cycle through each item in the array and use it's index to determine whether or not it is a multiple of four so i can create proper spacing for binary numbers.

```
def decimalToBinary(hu):

    bits = []
    h = []
    while hu > 0:
        kla = hu%2
        bits.append(kla)
        hu = int(hu/2)
    for i in reversed(bits):
        h.append(i)
    if len(h) <= 4:
        print (''.join(map(str,h)))
    else:
        for j in range(len(h)):
            h.index(1) = h.index(1)+1
            if h.index % 4 != 0:
                print (''.join(map(str,h)))
            elif h.index % 4 == 0:
                print (' '.join(map(str,h)))


decimalToBinary( 23 )
```

Comment: Sorry, its not clear for me What you want to do. Any example of input date, and expected output would be most useful?

Comment: cant u use builtin `bin` ???

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is the index of the list from `range(len(h))` in the `for` loop, then you can change that line to `for idx,j in enumerate(range(len(h))):` where `idx` is the index of the range.

Answer (score 0):

This line `h.index(1) = h.index(1)+1` is incorrect. Modified your function, so at least it executes and generates an output, but whether it is correct, i dont know. Anyway, hope it helps:

```
def decimalToBinary(hu):

    bits = []
    h = []
    while hu > 0:
        kla = hu%2
        bits.append(kla)
        hu = int(hu/2)
    for i in reversed(bits):
        h.append(i)
    if len(h) <= 4:
        print (''.join(map(str,h)))
    else:
        for j in range(len(h)):
            h_index = h.index(1)+1 # use h_index variable instead of h.index(1)
            if h_index % 4 != 0:
                print (''.join(map(str,h)))
            elif h_index % 4 == 0:
                print (' '.join(map(str,h)))


decimalToBinary( 23 )    

# get binary version to check your result against.
print(bin(23))
```

This results:

```
#outout from decimalToBinary
10111
10111
10111
10111
10111


#output from bin(23)
0b10111
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to join the bits to string and separate them every 4 bits. You could modify your code with Marcin's correction (by replacing the syntax error line and do some other improvements), but I suggest doing it more "Pythonically".

Here's my version:

```
def decimalToBinary(hu):

    bits = []
    while hu > 0:
        kla = hu%2
        bits.append(kla)
        hu = int(hu/2)
    h = [''.join(map(str, bits[i:i+4])) for i in range(0,len(bits),4)]
    bu = ' '.join(h)
    print bu[::-1]
```

Explanation for the h assignment line:

`range(0,len(bits),4)`: a list from 0 to length of `bits` with step = 4, eg. [0, 4, 8, ...]

`[bits[i:i+4] for i in [0, 4, 8]`: a list of lists whose element is every four elements from bits

eg. [ [1,0,1,0], [0,1,0,1] ...]

`[''.join(map(str, bits[i:i+4])) for i in range(0,len(bits),4)]`: convert the inner list to string

`bu[::-1]`: reverse the string

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning Python, it's good to do your way. As @roippi pointed out,

```
for index, value in enumerate(h):
```

will give you access to both index and value of member of h in each loop.

To group 4 digits, I would do like this:

```
def decimalToBinary(num):
    binary = str(bin(num))[2:][::-1]
    index = 0
    spaced = ''
    while index + 4 < len(binary):
        spaced += binary[index:index+4]+' '
        index += 4
    else:
        spaced += binary[index:]
    return spaced[::-1]

print decimalToBinary(23)
```

The result is:

```
1 0111
```